# Convert python dictionaries with Decimal keys to JSON using custom encoder

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, decimal

JSON only allows strings as keys.

The code below uses a custom JSONEncoder to turn `Decimal` values into strings.

Is there a way to specify an encoder that will turn `Decimal` keys into strings?

```
import json
import decimal

class DecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, decimal.Decimal):
            return str(obj)
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

d1 = {3: decimal.Decimal(50)}
print(json.dumps(d1, cls=DecimalEncoder))

d2 = {decimal.Decimal(50): 3}
json.dumps(d2, cls=DecimalEncoder)  # TypeError: keys must be a string
```

I am using `python3.6`.

Note: Obviously I could iterate through my dictionary and replace the Decimal types with string values, but I am hoping to find a more elegant solution perhaps by adding behaviour to the encoder.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't hook the handling of keys, you'll have to convert them *before* you encode. You can do so with a recursive handler like:

```
from functools import singledispatch

@singledispatch
def string_keys(obj):
    return obj

@string_keys.register(dict)
def _(d):
    return {str(k): string_keys(v) for k, v in d.items()}

@string_keys.register(list)
def _(l):
    return [string_keys(v) for v in l]
```

All this does is convert a nested structure of lists and dicts recursively where all keys are forced to be strings.

Use this when converting to JSON:

```
json_encoded = json.dumps(string_keys(data))
```

You can extend this to handle `Decimal` objects (outside of keys) too by adding another registry:

```
@string_keys.register(Decimal)
def _(d):
    return str(d)
```

Going the other way is a little tricky, unless you explicitly mark up `Decimal` keys (with a prefix, say), you can't easily distinguish between keys that were strings to start with and `Decimal` values. You could use a `try/except` approach here:

```
from functools import singledispatch

@singledispatch
def keys_to_decimal(obj):
    return obj

@keys_to_decimal.register(dict)
def _(d):
    def try_decimal(k):
        try:
            return Decimal(k)
        except ValueError:
            return k
    return {try_decimal(k): keys_to_decimal(v) for k, v in d.items()}

@keys_to_decimal.register(list)
def _(l):
    return [keys_to_decimal(v) for v in l]
```

Demo:

```
>>> string_keys([{Decimal(0): 'foo'}])
[{'0': 'foo'}]
>>> keys_to_decimal(string_keys([{Decimal(0): 'foo'}]))
[{Decimal('0'): 'foo'}]
```

Comment: I am getting this error `NameError: name 'k' is not defined` in the line 
`return {str(k): string_keys(v) for v in d}` .

Comment: @ChrisGuest: and another mistake in the `keys_to_decimal` handling; now actually tested. :-)